# email with php not sending email

Tags: php, email

I am trying to send an email with php everything seems to work but i dont get the email. No errors come up i just dont receive the email. any suggestions? here is my code:

```
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>mail</title>
<link href="loginmodule.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
    $email_to = "myemail@gmail.com";
    $email_subject = "MythMedia Account Reqe";


    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }

    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) 
        ) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');      
    }

    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required

    $error_message = "";

    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }

  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }


    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Password: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";



// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.Mythmedia."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);

?>



Thank you, I will process your account soon&trade;<br>

 <a href="login-form.php">Login</a>
<?php
}
?>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you sending from your server or from localhost?  If you are sending from localhost, do you have a sendmail server installed to actually send the email?

Comment: what is the error you receive?

Comment: please use `var_dump(mail($email...` and post the results. If everything is OK with the email parameters the dump should show a `bool(true)`.

Comment: What do you see? Do you see any output? Is `$_POST['email']` set, for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please check with this line

```
$headers = 'From: '.Mythmedia."\r\n".
```

I think you have to do something like

```
$Mythmedia='Mythmedia';
$headers = 'From: '.$Mythmedia."\r\n".
```

Or

```
$headers = 'From: Mythmedia \r\n'.
```

Comment: yes it looks to be a syntax error (unless `Mythmedia` is `DEFINED`)